# Custom validation error messages in Kohana 3.0

Tags: validation, kohana, kohana-3

I'm attempting to load custom error messages to use when validating my 'sign up' form.

**User model:**

https://github.com/ashleyconnor/Egotist/blob/master/classes/model/user.php

**Account Controller:**

https://github.com/ashleyconnor/Egotist/blob/master/classes/controller/user/account.php

**Sign Up View:**

https://github.com/ashleyconnor/Egotist/blob/master/views/account/signup.php

I then placed `user.php` in `/messages/models/user.php` but my new error messages are not being displayed in the form.

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

  return array
  (
     'username' => array
     (
        'not_empty' => 'your message',
        'max_length' => 'your message',
        'alpha_dash' => 'your message',
        'default' => 'default message'
     ),
  );

?>
```

https://github.com/ashleyconnor/Egotist/blob/master/messages/models/user.php

So submitting an empty form gives the following error messages:

- Username must not be empty
- Email Address must not be empty
- Password must not be empty

Which are the default ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Kohana `Validation` class, `errors` method source code:

```
 * Returns the error messages. If no file is specified, the error message
 * will be the name of the rule that failed. When a file is specified, the
 * message will be loaded from "field/rule", or if no rule-specific message
 * exists, "field/default" will be used. If neither is set, the returned
 * message will be "file/field/rule".
 *
 * By default all messages are translated using the default language.
 * A string can be used as the second parameter to specified the language
 * that the message was written in.
 *
 *     // Get errors from messages/forms/login.php
 *     $errors = $Validation->errors('forms/login');
```

Try using `$errors = $post->errors('models/user')` instead `$errors = $post->errors('signup')`

Comment: In addition, you have an error on line 26 of the controller:  `$errors = $_POST->errors('login');` 
It's trying to call the `errors()` method on the `$_POST` array - not an instance of the Validation class.

Comment: Actually when I modified this to `$post` it broke the validation on my login. This works as $_POST.